# How to update the dropdown-menu text after selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown-menu.

[image]

---

## HTML

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1"> <span class="summary-texts">Summary</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
       <!-- Dynamic List will added here  -->
   </ul>
</div>
```

the list in there is dynamically populate using JS.

---

## JS

```
for (var assignment in objects.assignments ) {

 $("#dd .dropdown").append('<li><a class="group" id="group-'+assignment+'">Group ' + assignment + '</a></li>');

 //Update the text 
 $("#dd .wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group ' + assignment);


}
```

I want to change "Summary" to whatever group that I selected.
I'm not sure my "Summary" keep displaying, even after I select any other groups.

I hope someone willing to give me a little help here.

Any tips / helps will be much appreciated.

Comment: As `#dd` and `.wrapper-dropdown-1`  are on the same `div`, you should not separate it, try `$("#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts").text('Group ' + assignment);`

Comment: I didn't know I can't do that. Thanks. Trying that now.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways you could do this, set the selector correctly:

```
"#dd.wrapper-dropdown-1 .summary-texts"
```

(note, no space)

or set an id on the "Summary" text:

```
<span id="summarytext" class="summary-texts">
```

and identify it with that ID.